# Extjs 1st combobox select loads data to 2nd combo box extjs4

Tags: php, zend-framework, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

```
listeners:{select:{fn:function(combo, value) {
                           var attribute = Ext.getCmp('attributes');
                           var feature = Ext.getCmp('features');
                           var store = Ext.getStore('product.CategoryAttributeComboBox');

                           attribute.setValue('');
                           attribute.setDisabled(false);
                           attribute.store.load({
                           params: {id: 5}
                         });
}}}
```

Above is my code to load the data to 2nd combo box.But when I click on first combo it does not populate data to 2nd one,and if I select the 1st combo again it loads data to 2nd combo.Dont really find whats is happening with code.Is there something happens with the "mode" feature local or remote.I have setup my mode to local.

Comment: Do you have the same store for those 2 comboboxes?

Comment: no there are two different stores for each combo box.

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I was simular issue and write simple plugin for combobox. May be can help for you. [See example on github](http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://github.com/werdender/ext4examples/blob/master/detailset.html).

Note: "change", "keyup" events not processing, edit if you need it.

Comment: The github example i have seen ,but is it working correctly?Bacuse if i am changing the option in combo,the 2nd combo continues to show all the options.

Comment: @anupkumar Yes, it was my issue requirements. You can use filters in store of combo. I edit my example, see on github again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another full example of two combo boxes interacting: 
http://extjs.wima.co.uk/example/1